# Hierarchical dependency and "The type is defined in an assembly that is not referenced"

Tags: c#

For example, I have three class libraries: `L1`, `L2` and `L3`. `L1` has type `T1`. `L2` has type `T2`. `L2` has reference to `L1`. `L3` has reference to `L2`. `L3` has NO explicit reference to `L1`.

It compiles and works absolutely okay if `T2` class looks like:

```
public class T2
{
    T1 GetT1() { ... };
}
```

But if `T2` uses `T1` as parameter in constructor, it says `T1 is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.` when I build `L3`:

```
public class T2
{
    T2(T1 t1) { ... };
    T1 GetT1() { ... };
}
```

Is it possible somehow to ignore this error? I do not use constructor with `T1` in `L3` and do not want to add reference to `L1`.

Answer (score 1):

When you expose the type in constructor it mandates a reference to type library.  This is a classic example of when to use either an interface or abstract class.